# Centralized git for a group

Tags: git, repository

We have a small work group that I would like to encourage to adopt git after being on SVN.  So, I am interested in getting the best of the central repository feel that SVN has to offer while getting all the best of git.  We don't tend to have a single large project but many smaller and unrelated projects, so they will likely be structured as multiple git repositories.  What would be folks' recommendations about how to move forward?  A few options:

1. Simple directory structure via ssh
2. Private github
3. Gitolite

We do not have ssh access to machines through our firewall (go figure), so access to local resources for us means going over http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A private GitHub is appealing to me since you don't have to worry about administering the repo server, ever. [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) is a really nice **free** alternative, which supports git these days, and doesn't charge for private repos:

> Store all of your Git and Mercurial source code in one place with unlimited private repositories. Includes issue tracking, wiki, and pull requests.

Comment: I had tried bitbucket back in the early days, had decided on github, and never looked back.  I should have....

Comment: BitBucket's changed quite a lot since the early days!

Answer (score 0):

A Linux VM sitting on some server with Gitolite on it has worked well for me for a number of years. The newest version allows you to update hooks among all other admin tasks via simple pushes to an admin repo. I would highly recommend it.